# Synchronize App Data Folder on Android 13

Tags: sync, android-13

I'm currently using Android 13 on my Phone (No Root, No CFW). Now i want to synchronize the data folder of a app on my Phone with my PC. Means i want to automatically upload/download changes.
The Problem is with apps like `syncthing` i'm not able to access the `/Android/data/<appfolder>` anymore.

Does someone has a solution how to do a synchronization without rooting the Device?